# How can I write a mocha unit test for an AWS SQS?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, amazon-sqs

My code is:

```
  const validateFile = function(file) {
    // DoStuff
  }

  const validatorConsumer = Consumer.create({
    queueUrl: 'https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/account-id/queue-name',
    handleMessage: (message, done) => {
      return FileLib.downloadFromBucket(message)
      .then(validateFile)
      .then(done)
    }
  })
```

I'm using the `sqs-consumer` package from `npm`. How do I write a unit test to see if it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you'd like to unit test the `handleMessage` function.

If you define the function in a separate node module, you can `require` it in your unit test as well as in your production code where you create the consumer. In your test you simply pass in a manually created message that could appear on the queue and a custom function for the `done` callback where you make your test assertions.

```
// messageHandler.js
module.export = function(message, done) {
    // message handler code...
    return FileLib.downloadFromBucket(message)
        .then(validateFile)
        .then(done)
    }
}

// main.js
const messageHandler = require('./messageHandler');
const validatorConsumer = Consumer.create({
    queueUrl: 'https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/account-id/queue-name',
    handleMessage: messageHandler
})

// messageHandler.test.js
const messageHandler = require('./messageHandler');
const message = '...' // create a sample message here

it('handles message correctly', done => {
    messageHandler(message, result => {
        // assertions go here...
        done();
    })
});
```